# How to resolve "Tridion is undefined" error in a Tridion popup page?

Tags: javascript, tridion

I am customizing the ribbon toolbar and adding a button to it. Whenever I click on that button, it will open a aspx page allows authors to select some data, which gets appended to the existing RTF field content.

But when popup is opened it is having the below error in the browser (Internet Explorer).

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;     SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Thu, 5 Apr 2012 12:18:35 UTC


Message: 'Tridion' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://172.21.188.26:2694/WebUI/Core/stringresources.js
```

I can't find stringresources.js file in the specified location. Please suggest me a way to solve the problem.

ButtonReference.js file:
    Type.registerNamespace("RTFExtensions.Commands");

```
RTFExtensions.Commands.ButtonReference = function Commands$ButtonReference(name) { 
    Type.enableInterface(this, "RTFExtensions.Commands.ButtonReference"); 
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.Command", [name || "ButtonReference"]); 
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.FaCommand", [name || "ButtonReference"]); 
}; 

RTFExtensions.Commands.ButtonReference.prototype._isAvailable = function         ButtonReference$_isAvailable(target) { 
    if (target.editor.getDisposed()) { 
        return false; 
    } 

    return true; 
}; 

RTFExtensions.Commands.ButtonReference.prototype._isEnabled = function ButtonReference$_isEnabled(target) { 
    if (!Tridion.OO.implementsInterface(target.editor, "Tridion.FormatArea") ||             target.editor.getDisposed()) { 
        return false; 
    } 

    return true; 
};

RTFExtensions.Commands.ButtonReference.prototype._execute = function     ButtonReference$_execute(target) {
    if (target.item.isActivePopupOpened()) {
        return;
    }

    function ButtonReference$execute$onPopupCanceled(event) {
        target.item.closeActivePopup();
    };

    //var url = $config.expandEditorPath("/Popups/PopupReference.aspx", "RTFExtensions"); 
    var schemaId = $display.getView().getItem().getSchemaId();
    var componentName = $display.getView().getItem().getTitle();
    //alert($display.getView().getItem().getId());
    alert($display.getView().getItem().getTitle());
    var url = "Editors/RTFExtensions/Popups/PopupReference.aspx?schemaId=" + schemaId + "&componentName=" + componentName;
    //var url = "Editors/RTFExtensions/Popups/PopupReference.aspx";
    alert("url is " + url);
    var dialogFeatures = $cme.Popups.ITEM_SELECT.FEATURES;
    var popup = $popup.create(url, dialogFeatures, null);

    $evt.addEventHandler(popup, "submit",
        function ButtonReference$execute$onPopupSubmitted(event) {
            // Update FA 
            var value = event.data.value;
            if (value) {
                alert("In Button Reference value:" + value);
                target.editor.applyHTML(value);
            }

            // Release 
            target.item.closeActivePopup();
        }
    );

    $evt.addEventHandler(popup, "unload", ButtonReference$execute$onPopupCanceled);

    target.item.setActivePopup(popup);
    popup.open();
};
```

PopupReference.js File:

```
Type.registerNamespace("RTFExtensions.Popups");

RTFExtensions.Popups.PopupReference = function (element) {
    Type.enableInterface(this, "RTFExtensions.Popups.PopupReference");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.View");
};

RTFExtensions.Popups.PopupReference.prototype.initialize = function () {
    alert("initialized");    
    $log.message("Initializing Button Reference popup...");
    this.callBase("Tridion.Cme.View", "initialize");

    var p = this.properties;
    var c = p.controls;

    p.HtmlValue = { value: null };
    c.SubmitButon = $("#Submit");   
    //asp dropdown
    //c.DropDown = $("#lookupvaluesDropdown");
    //alert($("#lookupvaluesDropdown").value + "in initialize");        
    $evt.addEventHandler(c.SubmitButon, "click", this.getDelegate(this._execute));

    //    $evt.addEventHandler(c.InsertButton, "OnSelectedIndexChanged", this.getDelegate(this._execute));
};

RTFExtensions.Popups.PopupReference.prototype._execute = function () {
    alert("executing");
    //alert($("#lookupvaluesDropdown").value);
    this.properties.HtmlValue.value = $("#lookupvaluesDropdown").value;
    alert(this.properties.HtmlValue.value + " in execute");
    this.fireEvent("submit", this.properties.HtmlValue);

    alert("after fire event");
    //$("#Submit").fireEvent("submit1", this.properties.HtmlValue);
    window.close();
};



$display.registerView(RTFExtensions.Popups.PopupReference);
```

PopupReference.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PopupReference.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="ButtonReference.Popups.PopupReference" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.Web.UI.Core" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %> 
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ui"  Namespace="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Controls" Assembly="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:cc="http://www.sdltridion.com/web/ui/core/controls">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Reference Button Popup</title>
    <cc:tridionmanager runat="server" editor="PowerTools2011">
        <dependencies runat="server">
            <dependency runat="server">Powertools2011.Example</dependency>
            <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</dependency>
            <dependency runat="server">Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </cc:tridionmanager>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>        
        <h1>
            Reference Button Popup
        </h1>
        <table>        
        <tr><td><asp:DropDownList ID="lookupvaluesDropdown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td></tr>
        <tr><td><asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" /></td></tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that the JavaScript from Tridion is not loaded. Did you include the

```
<cc:tridionmanager runat="server" editor="PowerTools">
```

UserControl on your popup page?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not included this tag. Can you please tell me where to include this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include this in your popup.aspx page. If you want (more) examples, checkout the PowerTools project on code.google.com. Search for: TridionManager in the entire project. This should give you enough info to get you started.

Comment: When I try to add the tag it is giving error like unknown tag prefix or filter. Do I need to place it 'c' as prefix?

Comment: Did you try 'c' as a prefix? This prefix is/should be defined in the web.config from your Tridion installation (web\webUI\WebRoot\Web.config). But of course you can/should declare it in your own web.config (if your Editor has a web.config)

Comment: I can find the entry in web.config. Still it is giving the same error. Do I need to perform any other configurations? Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your customization (popup) an Editor? Is it configured as a Virtual directory in IIS? Did you try to define the prefix in the page (popup) itself? Did you try to define this prefix in your web.config? Did you check out the PowerTools project?

Comment: I am sending some values to popup page as query strings. Before this I just used to open popup page in that case it is working fine. When I tried to open with Query strings then I am getting errors. Please help me.

Comment: Murali, can you please show the relevant code in your question? It will make it easier for Albert to actually understand what you've done and where your problem comes from.

Comment: @AlbertRomkes I provided my code please look into it and help me solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks oke. Things to check/try:
1. Did you set up the extension as described in the documentation? (IIS, virutal directory, etc)
2. Try to start with a minimum amount of code. Remove almost everything and add new code line by line (method by method) to see where it breaks. 
3. Check if the Tridion JS-libraries are loaded correctly (using Firebug) or try to execute a basic Tridion javascript function in the javascript console (Tridion for instance)

Comment: @AlbertRomkes Thanks for your respose. 1. I did the set up exactly how it is in the documentation. 2. I tried it line by line every thing is loading before I add two query strings in button reference.js file while creating the url. But when I try to add component name also in the url then it is giving the "'Tridion' undefined "error.why it is behaving like this? Even I replaced component name with component Id but no luck. It seems if we have two values in url then the error occuring. Please help me in this issue/ suggest me other way to achieve multiple url values without error?

Comment: @AlbertRomkes Do I need to provide my configuration file for GUI extension? I added <cc:tridionmanager runat="server" editor="PowerTools"> tag in aspx page but at tridionmanager and dependency "Element not supported" error I am getting. How to remove this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on my system. I do think (as said earlier) the Tridion JavaScript JS-libraries are not loaded. CAN YOU VERIFY THAT? See my comment above on how to do that. Also, if you use the <cc:TridionManager> your page has to inherit from 'Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionPage'. So, in your .aspx popup, change ' Inherits="ButtonReference.Popups.PopupReference" %>' to ' Inherits="Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionPage" %>'

Answer (score 3):

I might be repeating myself, but have you tried following any of the available Tutorials for creating a GUI extension?

Can you get any of those to work?

Hint: google for "Tridion gui extension tutorial"

Answer (score 3):

I recently got the same error, though likely for different reasons.

1. Robert Curlette (RCWeb) has a great guide on the two [now-familiar "broken" GUI screens](http://www.curlette.com/?p=269).
2. We also have a good tip from the [PowerTools wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/DevelopmentTools#Testing_and_Troubleshooting), specifically from Peter Kjaer:

> Visit the resource directly
>   http://{hostname}/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.{version
>   number}_.aspx?mode=js

I can see this in Chrome's console with a missing service dll. I get the same `Tridion is not defined` error, but another one for the Dashboard. You can right-click on the Dashboard_... link, open a new tab, and get more information.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.2_.aspx?mode=js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tridion is not defined stringresources.js:1
(anonymous function) stringresources.js:1
```

In my specific case, I had the following.

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\PowerTools\Model\Services\{one of the many outstanding contributions}.svc'.
```

Removing the offending file in the Model configuration file fixed my error. Though we may never know what really happened in the mysterious case of the Two Items in a Query String.